# Can volumeMounts: in kubernetes pod be optional

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have certain requirements where volumeMounts: should be an optional field.

```
spec:
      volumes:
        -
          name: aaa
          secret:
            secretName: aaa-certs
      containers:
        -
          name: my-celery
          volumeMounts:
            -
              name: aaa
              mountPath: /tmp/aaa_certs
              readOnly: true
```

If secret is present then it will mount, else create an empty folder. Is this possible

Comment: I'm not aware of an option like that. Maybe an empty secret will suffice?

Comment: As a general matter: No, you can't. But post more details about your environment and needs so we can help others. Does it need to be secrets? if not, maybe [Dynamic Volume Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) may solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secret volumes can be marked as optional using tag "optional: true", and result in empty directories if the associated secret doesn't exist, rather than blocking pod startup.

Example:

```
spec:
      volumes:
        -
          name: aaa
          secret:
            secretName: aaa-certs
            optional: true
      containers:
        -
          name: my-celery
          volumeMounts:
            -
              name: aaa
              mountPath: /tmp/aaa_certs
              readOnly: true
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible. You would need a higher level system like Helm or an operator to manage that kind of dynamic configuration.